# How many radiotherapy sessions would it take to boil one cup of water?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation

**Context**: Gray (Gy) is a unit dose used in radiotherapy. It is defined as the absorbed energy of 1J per kilogram of matter.

There is a wide misconception that ionizing radiation acts by heating tissues, because after some sessions of radiotherapy the skin may become red due to inflammation, similarly to when we get a burn.

**Goal**: I'd like to calculate how many standard sessions of radiation therapy would be required to boil one cup of water at standard ambient temperature and pressure. The standard daily dose is $1.8$Gy/day and we would assume that all sessions were given simultaneously (so that the water wouldn't cool off in the meantime).

I've done my calculations by converting converting calories to Joule etc, but could please somebody provide his/her version of it? Just to cross-validate my results? If noone answers, I'll post mine.

Comment: I recommend posting your own work & answer. That way it is less likely to be closed for a homework-like question.

Comment: To add to that: questions on this site should be asking for a specific physics concept, not just for a check of your calculations

Comment: $G=C\Delta T=350000\text{Gy}$
using $\Delta T\approx80\text{K}$ and $C=4.18\text{J}/\text{gK}$.

Comment: @BMs, Michiel feel free to vote for close if the question taints the site. No hard feelings :)

Answer (score 1):

Bringing $1 kg$ of water up to $373K$, from an assumed room temperature of $300K$:

$$h_f = m C_p \Delta T = 1 \times 4.178 \times (373 - 300) = 304.994~kJ$$

Supplying latent heat:

$$h_{fg} = L_{vap} \times m =  2260 \times 1 = 2260~kJ$$

Net heat required = $h_f + h_{fg} = 2564.994~kJ$

Suppose all of the radiation was converted to heat inside the water, it would take $2564.994 \times 10^3~Gy$, and taking $1.8~Gy/day$, it would take $1424996.667~days$, which is $\approx 3904~yr$